# How can increase the calendar size in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am polishing up an Access form, and I would like to increase the calendar selection panel because some people can't see it properly:

[image]

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're using the built-in DatePicker option in Access. Unfortunately this component is not customizable. However, you could suppress the use of the DatePicker and instead use a custom calendar form (as a subform on your main form). This would provide you with the flexibility to make the calendar as large as you need it to be for your users.

This isn't a trivial task, but there is a GitHub repo that contains a calendar form and a sample form illustrating how to incorporate the calendar form into an application. (You may need to customize the size of the calendar form for your particular use case, but the "hard part" of writing the calendar functionality has already been done).

The repo with the sample can be found here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Access-Replace-Calendar-Control